# I'm having trouble resetting passwords with Parse

Tags: swift, parse-server, reset-password

I am making my own app in Swift, and wanted to include the feature of resetting passwords using Parse. My console eventually shows a successful notice, but when I go to the email to see if Parse sent the email to reset password, I don't receive anything. Would really appreciate it if you could help me sort this issue :D [I've added a screenshot so that you can see what my console shows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPkqF.png)

```
 @IBAction func recoverPasswordButton(_ sender: Any) {

    PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmail(inBackground: emailTextField.text!, block: { (success, error) in

        if self.emailTextField != nil {

            self.displayAlert(title: "Check your email", message: "A link has been sent to recover your password. Follow the instructions.")

            print("A link to recover your password has been sent")

        } else {

            var errorText = "Unknown error: please try again"

            if let error = error {

                errorText = error.localizedDescription
            }
            self.displayAlert(title: "Email is not valid", message: errorText)

        }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Email verification, You need to add the setting in the dashboard like below

**The first thing is that Parse stops his support, you have to use Back4App.**

[image]

Comment: Are you working with parse or back4app?, Can you give me a screenshot of dashboard

Comment: So I have to migrate my information from parse to back4app? Also, how is Back4App different than Heroku? Which is best?

Comment: Now parse has stopped his services so back4app is same as parse. Now back4app is continuing parse services

Comment: How can I add an image in comments? Could I send you an email? I looked through the articles in back4app to migrate my information from my bitnami parse api and can't seem to find grasp the concept.

Comment: Yes sure, you can

Comment: jschoudhary01@gmail.com